# How create a sticky Navbar that is changing the color while scrolling? [with Typescript in Angular]

Tags: css, angular, typescript

I want to create a navbar like here: http://www.devoncrawford.io/

I couldn't figure it out how to interact with css elements through my ts code.
Maybe you can give me a tip, where I could research a bit more. 
I would also love to get this autoscrollbutoon and just be able to interact with my css stuff.

I found a lot of jQuery stuff, but I am not familiar with it. Is that working in angular and should I learn it?

Thanks for your time. Sorry, it is a little bit general question, but I hope you can give me some advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the below article which explain how to create sticky navbar using angular with good explanation and example

Ref:https://netbasal.com/reactive-sticky-header-in-angular-12dbffb3f1d3
Example:https://stackblitz.com/github/zetsnotdead/ng-reactive-sticky-header

Answer (score 0):

I would use an windows eventListener to look at the scroll movement.

window.addEventListener('scroll', this.scroll);

After the scroll hits a number of vertical pixels, you could change the navbar background-color from 'transparent' to the color you want. (in the examples case '#fff'. You could make two different classes with the different background-colors and append or remove the css class.

Hope this helps.